# Creating dummy variables for dataset with continuous and categorical variables in Python using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, variables

I am working on a logistic regression for employee turnover.
The variables I have are

```
q3attendance           object
q4attendance           object
average_attendance     object
training_days           int64
esat                 float64
lastcompany           object
client _category      object
qual_category         object
location             object
rating                object
role                  object
band                  object
resourcegroup         object
skill                 object
status                 int64
```

I have marked the categorical variables using

```
cat=[' bandlevel ',' resourcegroup ',' skill ',..}
```

I define x and y using `x=df.iloc[:,:-1]` and `y=df.iloc[:,-1]`.

Next I need to create dummy variables. So, I use the command

```
xd = pd.get_dummies(x,drop_first='True')
```

After this, I expect the continuous variables to remain as they are and the dummies to be created for all categorical variables. However, on executing the command, I find that the code is treating the continuous variables also as categorical and ends up creating dummies for all of them as well. So, it the tenure is 3 years 2 months, 4 years 3 months etc, 3.2 and 4.3 both are taken as categorical. I end up with more than 1500 dummies and it is a challenge to run the regression after that.

What am I missing? Should I specifically mark out the categorical variables when using `get_dummies`?

Comment: how should `get_dummies` know what your categorical values are?  Maybe define  `df_cat = df[cat]`, `x_cat = df_cat.iloc[:,:-1]`..., `xd_cat = pd.get_dummies(x_cat, drop_first=True)`

Answer (score 0):

[pd.get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) has a optional param `columns` which accepts list of columns for which you need to create encoding.

For example:

```
df.head()
+----+------+--------------+-------------+---------------------------+----------+-----------------+
|    |   id | first_name   | last_name   | email                     | gender   | ip_address      |
|----+------+--------------+-------------+---------------------------+----------+-----------------|
|  0 |    1 | Lucine       | Krout       | lkrout0@sourceforge.net   | Female   | 199.158.46.27   |
|  1 |    2 | Sherm        | Jullian     | sjullian1@mapy.cz         | Male     | 8.97.22.209     |
|  2 |    3 | Derk         | Mulloch     | dmulloch2@china.com.cn    | Male     | 132.108.184.131 |
|  3 |    4 | Elly         | Sulley      | esulley3@com.com          | Female   | 63.177.149.251  |
|  4 |    5 | Brocky       | Jell        | bjell4@huffingtonpost.com | Male     | 152.32.40.4     |
|  5 |    6 | Harv         | Allot       | hallot5@blogtalkradio.com | Male     | 71.135.240.164  |
|  6 |    7 | Wolfie       | Stable      | wstable6@utexas.edu       | Male     | 211.31.189.141  |
|  7 |    8 | Harcourt     | Dunguy      | hdunguy7@whitehouse.gov   | Male     | 224.214.43.40   |
|  8 |    9 | Devina       | Salerg      | dsalerg8@furl.net         | Female   | 49.169.34.38    |
|  9 |   10 | Missie       | Korpal      | mkorpal9@wunderground.com | Female   | 119.115.90.232  |
+----+------+--------------+-------------+---------------------------+----------+-----------------+
```

then

```
columns = ["gender"]
pd.get_dummies(df, columns=columns)


+----+------+--------------+-------------+---------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------+
|    |   id | first_name   | last_name   | email                     | ip_address      |   gender_Female |   gender_Male |
|----+------+--------------+-------------+---------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------|
|  0 |    1 | Lucine       | Krout       | lkrout0@sourceforge.net   | 199.158.46.27   |               1 |             0 |
|  1 |    2 | Sherm        | Jullian     | sjullian1@mapy.cz         | 8.97.22.209     |               0 |             1 |
|  2 |    3 | Derk         | Mulloch     | dmulloch2@china.com.cn    | 132.108.184.131 |               0 |             1 |
|  3 |    4 | Elly         | Sulley      | esulley3@com.com          | 63.177.149.251  |               1 |             0 |
|  4 |    5 | Brocky       | Jell        | bjell4@huffingtonpost.com | 152.32.40.4     |               0 |             1 |
|  5 |    6 | Harv         | Allot       | hallot5@blogtalkradio.com | 71.135.240.164  |               0 |             1 |
|  6 |    7 | Wolfie       | Stable      | wstable6@utexas.edu       | 211.31.189.141  |               0 |             1 |
|  7 |    8 | Harcourt     | Dunguy      | hdunguy7@whitehouse.gov   | 224.214.43.40   |               0 |             1 |
|  8 |    9 | Devina       | Salerg      | dsalerg8@furl.net         | 49.169.34.38    |               1 |             0 |
|  9 |   10 | Missie       | Korpal      | mkorpal9@wunderground.com | 119.115.90.232  |               1 |             0 |
+----+------+--------------+-------------+---------------------------+-----------------+-----------------+---------------+
print(tabulate())
```

will encode only column `gender`

All data is auto-generated, doesn't represent real world

Comment: Thank you. Is there any limit on the number of columns?

Comment: No, you can add as many columns as you need and can and also specify the naming (prefix or suffix) of the new columns.